# ¿Como puedo hacer que NVIM guarde archivos mas facil?

Tags: vim

Hola estoy aprendiendo a utilizar nvim y me incomoda que cada vez que quiero guardar un archivo tengo que usar el :w quisiera saber si existe una opcion mas facil para hacer el guardado mas facil

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bienvenido Yared Mh a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Fácil es algo muy relativo, <kbd>:w</kbd> es bastante simple y si piensas que tal vez te toque trabajar con Vim en entornos dónde tal vez no funcionen ciertas teclas especiales, me parece que es una combinación práctica.

Ahora bien, si estás más cómodo con combinaciones al estilo Windows, una que suelo configurar es asociar el guardar a la tecla <kbd>F2</kbd>, puedes agregar esto a tu `.vimrc`

```
nmap <silent><F2> :Update<CR>
imap <silent><F2> <c-o>:Update<CR>
```

Esto configura el <kbd>F2</kbd> en el modo "normal" y en el de "insert"

Nota: `:Update` o `:up` es un comnando de Vim que guarda de igual forma que `:w` pero con la particularidad (interesante) de solo modificar la fecha de escritura en el caso que el buffer realmente hubiera cambiado con respecto al archivo.