# Atajo de teclado para guardar un script en vim

Tags: vim

Estoy usando vim para programar junto con un plugin que me permite abrir una consola de comandos en el editor, que me ayuda a ejecutar mi script, y como ya saben es necesario guardar antes de ejecutar, el problema que tengo con esto es que se me hace muy lento tener que dar ***escape*** y escribir ***:w*** cada vez que quiero guardar un archivo para posteriormente ejecutarlo, así que necesito un atajo de teclado que me permita simplemente guardar el archivo, así como en otros editores pulsas ***ctrl + s*** para unicamente guardar el archivo.
Conozco un atajo en vim que me permite guardar y cerrar un archivo: ***shift + zz***, pero el problema es que me cierra el editor, ¿como hago para guardar unicamente el archivo mediante un atajo de teclado?

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476849/como-puedo-hacer-que-nvim-guarde-archivos-mas-facil

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: ???, hackiaron a Arcanis o que

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creando atajo `Ctrl + s` para guardar en Vim**

Hola, una solución a este problema es crear un atajo de teclado en tu archivo `.vimrc`. La mayoría de editores cuenta con el atajo `Ctrl + s` para guardar. Puedes recrear este atajo en vim o nvim con el siguiente código:

```
  nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
   imap <c-s> <c-o>:w<CR>
```

Guarda el código en tu .vimrc, esto habilitara el comando guardar con el atajo Ctrl + s. Eso si, es posible que algún plugin ya utiliza este atajo para alguna funcion, si es así; solo se debe reasignar ese atajo por otro y dejar el Ctrl + s para guardar.

**Explicación del código**

- `nmap` Creara atajo en modo normal.
- `imap` Creara atajo en modo insertar.
- `<c-s>` Indica que el atajo será Ctrl + s. Esto indica que si deseas un atajo Ctrl + w seria así: `<c-w>`
- `:w<CR>` Esto indica que el comando a ejecutar será :w (Guardar), el `<CR>` indica un enter.
- `<c-o>:w<CR>` Aquí la diferencia del anterior es que incluye `<c-o>` esto se agrega para el atajo en modo insertar, esto permite que el :w se ejecute en el área de comandos de vim, sino lo incluyera el :w aparecería en el texto que este editando.

**Atajo en lua**

Ahora Nvim 5.0 tiene mejor soporte para lua. Por lo tanto puedes crear este mismo atajo en el archivo de configuracion  lua. El codigo seria el siguiente:

```
map('n', '<c-s>', ':w<CR>', {noremap = true})
map('i', '<c-s>', '<c-o>:w<CR>', {noremap = true})
```

Conclusión, con estos ajustes en el archivo de configuración de Vim, se puede obtener el atajo guardar `Ctrl + s` que es muy popular en muchos editores.